# How to get user id from database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I'm writing an application in node.js/angular and wants to get the user id to my index.html file but have been unable to using:

```
<a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/mytests/{{ main.getId }}">My tests</a>
```

I'm quite sure this is because the token that gets decoded does not contain the user id but I haven't been able to add it.

When i needed the user id of every user in the database it worked using the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in management.users | filter: searchFilter | limitTo: management.limit">
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.email }}</td>
    <td>
     <!-- Edit Button -->
        <a href="/edit/{{ person._id }}">
            <button type="button" ng-show="management.editAccess" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </a>
       <!-- Delete Button -->
       <button type="button" ng-click="management.deleteUser(person.username);" ng-show="management.deleteAccess" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not really sure if this is the best technique to get the user id which is stored on the local db or if there is a better way? If you have any suggestions on how to get it i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>{{ person.id }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a ng-href="/edit/{{ person._id }}" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; color:black">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this :

```
<span ng-bind="person._id"></span>
```